# Quectel EG25 modem not connecting with pppd

Tags: modem, pppd, quectel

I am trying to debug a Quectel EG25 modem connection.

Signal strength seems all right (I got an external antenna connected):

```
+CSQ: 31,99
```

SIM card is present and unlocked:

```
+CPIN: READY
```

APN is set right:

```
+CGDCONT: 1,"IP","wireless.twilio.com","0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0
```

Here is the chat script:

```
ABORT "BUSY"
ABORT "NO CARRIER"
ABORT "NO DIALTONE"
ABORT "ERROR"
ABORT "NO ANSWER"
TIMEOUT 30
"" AT
OK ATE0
OK ATI;+CSUB;+CSQ;+COPS?;+CGREG?;+CGDCONT?;&D2
OK ATD*99#
CONNECT
```

Here's what `pppd call quectel-connect` gives:

```
pppd options in effect:
debug       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
nodetach        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
dump        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
noauth      # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
remotename 3gppp        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
/dev/modem03        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
115200      # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
lock        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
connect chat -s -v -f /etc/chatscripts/quectel-chat-connect     # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
disconnect chat -s -v -f /etc/chatscripts/quectel-chat-disconnect       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
nocrtscts       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
modem       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
asyncmap 0      # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-echo-failure 4      # (from /etc/ppp/options)
lcp-echo-interval 30        # (from /etc/ppp/options)
hide-password       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
novj        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
novjccomp       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
ipcp-accept-local       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
ipcp-accept-remote      # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
ipparam 3gppp       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
noipdefault     # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
ipcp-max-failure 300        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
defaultroute        # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
noccp       # (from /etc/ppp/peers/quectel-pppd)
noipx       # (from /etc/ppp/options)
abort on (BUSY)
abort on (NO CARRIER)
abort on (NO DIALTONE)
abort on (ERROR)
abort on (NO ANSWER)
timeout set to 30 seconds
send (AT^M)
expect (OK)
^M
OK
 -- got it

send (ATE0^M)
expect (OK)
^M
^M
OK
 -- got it

send (ATI;+CSUB;+CSQ;+COPS?;+CGREG?;+CGDCONT?;&D2^M)
expect (OK)
^M
^M
Quectel^M
EG25^M
Revision: EG25GGBR02A02N2A^M
^M
SubEdition: V07^M
^M
+CSQ: 31,99^M
^M
+COPS: 0,0,"XYZ",2^M
^M
+CGREG: 0,2^M
^M
+CGDCONT: 1,"IP","wireless.twilio.com","0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0^M
^M
OK
 -- got it

send (ATD*99#^M)
expect (CONNECT)
^M
^M
CONNECT
 -- got it

Script chat -s -v -f /etc/chatscripts/quectel-chat-connect finished (pid 2096), status = 0x0
Serial connection established.
using channel 5
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/modem03
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xebf115f5> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0xc <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xdf2e25a3> <pcomp> <accomp>]
No auth is possible
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0xc <auth chap MD5>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xebf115f5> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0xd <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xdf2e25a3> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0xd <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xdf2e25a3> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xebf115f5]
kernel does not support PPP filtering
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0xe magic=0xdf2e25a3]
rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xdf2e25a3 eb f1 15 f5]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x3 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x4 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x4 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x5 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x5 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x6 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x6 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x7 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x7 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x8 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x8 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x9 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x9 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xa <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xb <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xb <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xc <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xc <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xd <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xd <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xe <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xe <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xf <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xf <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x10 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x10 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x11 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x11 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x12 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x13 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x13 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x14 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x14 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x15 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x15 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x16 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x16 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x17 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x17 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x18 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x18 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x19 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x19 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1a <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1a <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1b <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1b <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1c <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1c <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1d <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1d <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1e <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x1 magic=0xebf115f5]
rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x1 magic=0xdf2e25a3 eb f1 15 f5]
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
```

Are there other things I should check? Can you tell from the pppd logs what fails? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following the discussion from this thread https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=467004 it seems that DNS `10.11.12.13` is a bogus DNS address set by `pppd` when it cannot fetch the DNS server address from the modem. It might be a communication issue between `pppd` and the modem firmware.

My workaround is to invoke `pppd` with an explicit DNS server:

```
pppd ms-dns 8.8.8.8 call quectel-pppd
```